# SQLite Primary field (EditText)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having a problem thinking of the best solution for my android app. I have a field for ID number and it is a primary key. how can i make my app to not crash when this field is empty. Instead should ask the user to input the number.

Because currently when the id field is empty the app will crash. here is my code:

```
try {
                if (id.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please don't leave ID field empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID Already Exists.Please input a unique ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    if (id.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || fname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || lname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || course.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || year.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else
                        values.put("StudID", id.getText().toString());
                    values.put("StudFname", fname.getText().toString());
                    values.put("StudLname", lname.getText().toString());
                    values.put("StudCourse", course.getText().toString());
                    values.put("StudYearLevel", year.getText().toString());
                    dbase.insert("StudentFile", null, values);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Dont leave id field empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
if (id.getText().toString().length().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please don't leave ID field empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

or,

```
if (id.getText().toString()== null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please don't leave ID field empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

or,

```
    if (id.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please don't leave ID field empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```